# Change Floating Action Button Background

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, floating-action-button

I am using a floating action button and its image changes when its clicked. i have a flag and i store it in shared preferences. when it is true icon becomes like.png, when it is false icon becomes dislike.png.

I want to change its icon according to flag variable but when the app starts its icon is default which is true.png

How can I set the icon via shared preferences?

```
public class ReadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FloatingActionButton fab;
private boolean flag;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_read);

    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    getRate(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView());

    if(flag==false){
        fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);
    }

    else if(flag==true){
       fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.dislike);
    }

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            getRate(v);

            if(flag==false) {
                rateUp();
                Snackbar.make(v, "Vote +1", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                saveRate(v, true);
                fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.dislike);
            }

            else if(flag==true){
                rateDown();
                Snackbar.make(v, "Vote -1", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                saveRate(v, false);
                fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);

            }
        }
    });


}

public void rateUp() {};
public void rateDown() {};



public void saveRate(View view, boolean flag){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Rates", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(id, flag);
    editor.commit();
}

public void getRate(View view){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Rates", MODE_PRIVATE);

    flag = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(id, false);

}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
public class ReadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FloatingActionButton fab;
private string getSharedPreferencesId="getSharedPreferencesId";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_read);

    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    boolean flag=getRate();

    if(flag==false){
        fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);
    }

    else if(flag==true){
       fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.dislike);
    }

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            boolean flag=getRate();

            if(flag==false) {
                rateUp();
                Snackbar.make(v, "Vote +1", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                saveRate(true);
                fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.dislike);
            }

            else if(flag==true){
                rateDown();
                Snackbar.make(v, "Vote -1", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                saveRate(false);
                fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);

            }
        }
    });


}

public void rateUp() {};
public void rateDown() {};



public void saveRate(boolean flag){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Rates", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(getSharedPreferencesId, flag);
    editor.commit();
}

public boolean getRate(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Rates", MODE_PRIVATE);
    flag = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(getSharedPreferencesId, false);
}


}
```

Comment: But I want the change the icon when app start

Comment: you can use this code in ReadActivity fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color
                    .parseColor("#33691E")));

Comment: i am asking a complete different question

Answer (score 0):

I made some improvements on your code:

```
public class ReadActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private FloatingActionButton fab;
private boolean flag;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_read);

    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    flag = getRate();

    if(flag)
        fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.dislike);
    else
       fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            flag = getRate();

            if(flag) {
                rateDown();
                Snackbar.make(v, "Vote -1", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                saveRate(false);
                fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.like);
            }
            else{
                rateUp();
                Snackbar.make(v, "Vote +1", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                saveRate(true);
                fab.setImageResource(R.drawable.dislike);
            }
        }
    });


}

public void rateUp() {};
public void rateDown() {};



public void saveRate(boolean flag){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Rates", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(id, flag);
    editor.commit();
}

public boolean getRate(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Rates", MODE_PRIVATE);

    boolean flag = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(id, false);
    return flag;
}


}
```

Also check your activity_read.xml file. If you have set an image on your xml  FloatingActionButton, it will always use that image as default.

Comment: nothing changed, still same. `getRate()` returns its default value which is false when i start the activity. But icon changes when I call `onClick()`

Answer (score 0):

I will tell you the logic. Assumed you have many different contents and you want to save rating data for each content.

First, you need to store your each content's rating data into somewhere(Local or Remote DB, SharedPreferences, File etc.)

After starting your ReadActivity,

1. Set your flag to default value you wanted to be.
2. Set your FAB icon as default.
3. Get your related content rating data(boolean) from where you stored before.
4. Check if your rating data is true or false.
5. If it's true set your icon R.drawable.dislike, else set R.drawable.like
6. When you clicked the FAB, change your flag value and FAB icon
7. Save your new boolean value to where you stored before

The important point is, you must have different values for each content you have.

**EDIT:**

Try using getApplicationContext() before using getSharedPreferences()
Also you can try editor.apply() instead of editor.commit();

commit() and apply() does the same work but there are two differences, **apply() works asynchronously** and **commit() returns boolean value.**

```
public void saveRate(View view, boolean flag){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Rates", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean(id, flag);
    editor.apply();
}

public void getRate(View view){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Rates", MODE_PRIVATE);

    flag = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(id, false);

}
```

Comment: I thought and did the same as you mentioned and FAB icon changes when I click on it, there is no problem. When I call `getRate()` on activity start, it automatically returns the default value of sharedPreference.

Comment: doesn't work neither. thanks for help, I will try a different trick.